# spring ignoreResourceNotFound is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

I have configured a property file like below

```
<bean id="applicationHostProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"></property>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:applicationHost.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

From my spring bean I am injecting the property file

```
@Value("#{appsDeployedProperties}")
private Properties appsDeployedProperties;
```

Since I have set **ignoreResourceNotFound=true**, I am not expecting any error if the property file is not found.

But my spring context initialization fails, if the property file is missing. Am I doing something wrong here ? Thanks for your help.

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
> Error creating bean with name 'instanceConfigurati
>     on': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appsDeployedProperties': Ex
>     pression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel
>     .SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'appsDeployedProper
>     ties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.confi
>     g.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springfram
>     ework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested e
>     xception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E
>     :(pos 0): Property or field 'appsDeployedProperties' cannot be found on object o
>     f type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' -
> maybe
>     not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDe
>     pendencyException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceConfiguration': Unsati
>     sfied dependency expressed through field 'appsDeployedProperties': Expression pa
>     rsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvalua
>     tionException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'appsDeployedProperties' canno
>     t be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpre
>     ssionContext' - maybe not public?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans
>     .factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
>      org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): P
>     roperty or field 'appsDeployedProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org
>     .springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
>     ostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.j
>     ava:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject
>     (InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
>     ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
>     :349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Comment: Added the error stack trace

Comment: can you please reformat the stacktrace, it is not readable in this form

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind keys from `applicationHost.properties` as `String` rather than `Properties`. For example, if you have key `appsDeployedProperties` in `applicationHost.properties`, as follows:

**applicationHost.properties**

```
appsDeployedProperties=hello
```

In Spring Bean, you have to use as String, like:

```
@Value("#{appsDeployedProperties}")
private String appsDeployedProperties;
```

P.S: You can add `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` key with value as `true` to tell Spring to ignore keys used in bean which are not mentioned in any property file, as follows:

```
<bean id="applicationHostProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"></property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:applicationHost.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```